# How to scrape and implement GET request data

Tags: php, curl, get, web-scraping

I'm scraping [www.bbc.com](http://www.bbc.co.uk/) (for testing purposes) and Im having trouble getting the dynamic data to work. There is a weather widget on the site that I would like to work properly.

If you go to this website:

```
http://albafacility.nl/api_test2?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2F&elm=website
```

You will see my scraped version of bbc.com.
If you scroll down to the weather widget you will see "Edit my location" If you fill in "Amsterdam" a drop down list with options is presented. If you click on the list item nothing will happen. At first this was because of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` so to overcome that problem I scraped the file of the response. This is from the call of the original website:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/wwhp?module=weather&action=set&location_id=2759794
```

This is my own scraped version:

```
http://albafacility.nl/weather?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fwwhp%3Fmodule%3Dweather%26action%3Dset%26location_id%3D2759794
```

As you can see they are identical. So my question is: Why is the data not being populated within the widget? I don't see errors in console.

Comment: thanks,Looking in to it

Comment: @ 웃웃웃웃웃 Don't you mean `url decode`? Because I'm already encoding it (js) as you can see in the URL

Comment: use `url_encode` while sending data via url and use `url_decode` for decoding the same

Comment: Im already encoding it with `encodeURIComponent(url)` (javascript) isn't that the same..?

Comment: Can you explain why I would encode/decode? Im getting the proper results as you can see in the last url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very poor html on source when I have browsed your page. You should do few things like below when you are pushing this on your javascript widget.

1) replace all the **\"** with **"**
2) replace all the **\/** with **/**
3) **\>** should be **/>**
4) you have **title="Light src ="** in your source, and it should be **title="Light" src ="** [notice i have added a quote(") after the Light]